# Extract result of MySQL SELECT statement that is part of a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, subquery

The following SQL script returns;

> ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'tams_event_det_f.LastEventDate' in 'field list'.

Removing `LastEventDate` from the initial `SELECT` statement fixes the error, but it also means that field will not be added to the output table.

`LastEventDate` is declared within the inner `SELECT` query of the `WHERE` clause of the `INNER JOIN`, thus making it out of scope from the main query.

How can I bring `LastEventDate` into the scope of the main query in order to display the result in the output table?

```
SELECT drivers.driver_key,
        driver_name,
        driver_sitename,
        LastEventDate,
        SUM(trips.trip_distance)
FROM drivers
    INNER JOIN trips ON drivers.driver_key = trips.driver_key
WHERE trips.trip_date > (
        SELECT MAX(event_date) AS LastEventDate
        FROM events
        WHERE events.driver_key = drivers.driver_key
    )
GROUP BY DriverKey
ORDER BY DistanceSince DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the subquery to a derived table and join it:

```
SELECT
  d.driver_key,
  d.driver_name,
  d.driver_sitename,
  e.last_event_date,
  SUM(t.trip_distance) distance_since
FROM drivers d
INNER JOIN trips t ON d.driver_key = t.driver_key
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT driver_key, MAX(event_date) AS last_event_date
    FROM events
    GROUP BY driver_key
)  e ON e.driver_key = d.driver_key and t.trip_date > e.last_event_date
GROUP BY d.driver_key, d.driver_name, d.driver_name
ORDER BY distance_since DESC;
```

Side notes:

- I changed the `GROUP BY`  clause of your query so it includes all non-aggrated colums (your original code was not valid standard SQL, although some versions of MySQL allows such syntax by default)
- I added table aliases, which make the query easier to read and write

Answer (score 1):

The drivers table in the inner subquery can't access to the outer table reference so you should use a proper inner join inside the subquery

```
 SELECT
  drivers.driver_key,
  driver_name,
  driver_sitename,
  LastEventDate,
  SUM(trips.trip_distance)
FROM drivers
INNER JOIN trips
ON drivers.driver_key = trips.driver_key
WHERE trips.trip_date > (
  SELECT
    MAX(event_date) AS LastEventDate
    FROM events
    INNER JOIN drivers on  events.driver_key = drivers.driver_key
)
GROUP BY DriverKey
ORDER BY DistanceSince DESC;
```

but could use a proper inner join for the max value also

```
 SELECT
      drivers.driver_key,
      driver_name,
      driver_sitename,
      LastEventDate,
      SUM(trips.trip_distance)
    FROM drivers
    INNER JOIN trips ON drivers.driver_key = trips.driver_key
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
        driver_key, MAX(event_date) AS LastEventDate
        FROM events
        INNER JOIN drivers ON events.driver_key = drivers.driver_key
        group by  driver_key
    ) t t.driver_key = drivers.driver_key 
        AND trips.trip_date > t.LastEventDate 

    GROUP BY DriverKey
    ORDER BY DistanceSince DESC;
```